# Why does XSL/XPath think that this zero is a string?

Tags: xml, xslt

When executing this XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="numDeps" select="count(wd:Deps)"/>
<xsl:variable name="depRelation_FieldMaxLength" select="16 * 2"/>
<xsl:variable name="relationFieldRemainingBlanks" select="$depRelation_FieldMaxLength - ($numDeps*2)"/>
<xsl:variable name="spacesNeeded" select="max(0, $relationFieldRemainingBlanks)"/>
```

It produces the error: "1 error detected. Required item type of second argument of max() is xs:string; supplied value has item type xs:integer" Which seems to indicate that the first argument of `max()` is being interpreted as a string, rather than as an integer.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of the `max` function can be a sequence of values in the form `max((0, $relationFieldRemainingBlanks))`. With your call you try to apply `max` to the sequence formed by the `0` value and `$relationFieldRemainingBlanks` being treated as the second (optional) argument expected to be a collation (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-max).